# Ruby: Permutation on an Array

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

Say, I have an array:

```
a = [1,2]
```

and

```
n = 3
```

I want output like this:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

This are all possible combinations of length `n` of elements from array `a`.

Most importantly I'm using ruby 1.8.7

Comment: please explain why these down votes.

Comment: Please always comment when down voting a question.

Comment: @reto I'm really disappointed about this down-vote. :( . I don't know why all these people who have thousands of reputations do this stuff. I'm really gonna give up to asking question here in this forum. :(. I'm a learner but they don't understand but hurry to get more and more reputations.

Comment: it's a bad habit of StackOverflow users to sometimes downvote something that's already down-voted. They use it as an 'I agree button', although the question by itself, compared to other case, isn't that bad. I personally find it rude to downvote without at least taking the time to comment, but others might have a different opinion.

Comment: So: Don't worry too much and don't take it personally... I hope this will get reopened again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test in detail before use:

```
x = [1,0]
n = 3

def perm(a, n)
  l = a.length
  (l**n).times do |i|
    entry = []
    o = i
    n.times do
      v = o % l
      entry << a[v]
      o /= l
    end
    yield(i, entry)
  end
end

perm(x, n) do |i, entry|
  puts "#{i} #{entry.reverse.inspect}"
end
```

prints

```
0 [0, 0, 0]
1 [0, 0, 1]
2 [0, 1, 0]
3 [0, 1, 1]
4 [1, 0, 0]
5 [1, 0, 1]
6 [1, 1, 0]
7 [1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: (note to self: repeated_combination uses recursive implementation)

Answer (score 5):

```
a.repeated_combination(n).to_a
```

Comment: @rony36 the [backports gem](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) provides an implementation of [`repeated_combination`](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master/lib/backports/1.9.2/array/repeated_combination.rb)